# RegEx to exclude substring from end of string

Tags: regex, dynatrace

I am working at the user tagging cleanup regex for Dynatrace user session,

using the CSS selector i manage to grab the current user name from the MS SharePoint web page top header,

the output of such CSS seletion is one of the following two, with username and tooltip separated either by one space or by a new line:

```
Smith, John Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window).
```

or

```
Smith, John
Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window).
```

which regex can i now use to only grab string `John Smith` and nothing else regardless if name is followed by a space or a new line? Of course the string John Smith is not fixed it can be any user name.

Comment: What is the specific sentence structure and patterns that your data follows? Can names contain `-'é.`, etc? Can names begin with lowercase letters `Leonardo da Vinci` or contain initials `Mr. T.`?

Comment: @ctwheels name is alphanumeric and always in the form last name, first name

Comment: So always `Smith, John`? And includes only `a-zA-Z0-9`? How sure are you that there aren't special cases: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)?

Comment: @ctwheels it is irrelevant because my question here is about how to remove all from Use SHIFT.... and keep the name rather than what chars are included in the name...

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly, there's a static substring `Use SHIFT`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    (.*,.*)[ \n]

Where (.*,.*) are the last name, first name - which will be captured;
followed by a space or new line [ \n] which is not captured

This is the working one:
(.*, .*?)[ \n]

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I have now resolved using this regex:

```
(.+?)Use SHIFT\+ENTER to open the menu \(new window\)\.
```